# Second ODBC UPDATE call without a 1s delay causes first to not happen

Tags: odbc

I'm making a couple of calls in a loop into a custom API to update a table in an SQL database, and I found that if I perform the second one immediately, the first one does not actually change the database. If I wait one second between calls, it works.

These two calls were originally only made after individual UI button presses, so this is likely the first time anyone ever tried doing it twice in a row so quickly after each other. We had a feature request that now requires it though.

A hardcoded sleep() is good for tracking down the issue, but it really goes against the grain to consider that a *solution*. So I'd like to know what needs to be done in ODBC to ensure a previous operation on a table has completed so that the next one won't fail. But again, I'm a total ODBC noob, so I'm not familiar with how its API is supposed to be used (and of course the author of this code left the company over 6 months ago).

Tracking through the layers of API code, I found

- Everything ends in Windows ODBC calls.
- A single handle for a single connection (from SQLAllocHandle ) is used for all calls.
- The query in question is roughly `UPDATE table_name SET ... BEGIN INSERT INTO table_name (...) VALUES (...); END`
- The call sequence for each query seems to be:

  SQLCancel();
  check(SQLPrepare());
  check(SQLExecute());
  SQLCancel();

Where `check()` is:

```
if (code != SQL_SUCCESS && code != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
    exception();
}
```

The main issue I see here is that warnings will be totally ignored. But my noob reading of things is that if the query is still running at the end of the call, it should have gone into exception() with something like HYT00 (Timeout expired), right?

The only other thing I can think is that another thread might be calling this API on the same connection, and cancelling the operation with its SQLCancel(). I'll go triple check that, but I'm pretty sure that's not happening.